# How to change the order of tabs in JTabbedPane in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, tabs, jtabbedpane

This should hopefully be a very easy question.

Within Netbeans, using the GUI Swing editor I have four panels within a JTabbedPane.

Tab #4 I want to sit where Tab #1 is now, but I created it last so by default its at the end of the list.

How to I move it in the GUI in Netbeans?

Google has not been my friend on this one. I keep coming up with questions about tab order, (e.g. Tabbing through forms), rather than what I actually want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right Click on the **JTabbedPane->Change Order->You will get option to Move Up and Move Down** which will change the order of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Select your JFrame or JPanel or etc and then jTextField or jButton or etc of the selected JFrame and go to properties of the JField or JButton and enable the "focusCycleRoot" (this JField or JButton will be selected  first in the jFrame or JPanel )  then select the "change order"  of the JFrame or JPanel in the Navigator window and "Move up" or "Move down" to  change the order.![image: change tab order for JFrame or JPanel in netbeans]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do it in the GUI, but I hacked the .form file while Netbeans was closed and was able to move it. As a result, that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Navigator tab in the Netbeans IDE (Window > Navigator). You can expand the JTabbedPane node to show a list of the JPanels representing its tabs. Simply drag one JPanel node to another position in the list and the tabs will be re-ordered in the JTabbedPane design.