# How to change the order of tabs in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I know the title is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917389/how-to-change-the-order-of-tabs-in-jtabbedpane-in-netbeans), but I think it is different. I am not asking how to change order in IDE when I development/design, actually I want to do 'drag and drop' the tabs when my SWING application is running. Is it possible?

If it is not possible, I am thinking about adding 2 buttons on each member JPanel to move this tab back/forward. Now the question is, when I click a tab(say no.4 of 7 tabs), then I click the button on this chosen panel to move itself, how can I keep it 'focused' like no.4 penal is always shown even I call some method to re-organize the tabs?

Comment: You're right, it's not a duplicate of the question you linked, this is a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry that I did not search with word 'drag'/'draggable'

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement Drag and Drop functionality on the Tab components. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) has a tutorial on the implementation of Drag-and-Drop, and I recommend visiting the following page to see a discussion with examples for how this can be implemented: [How to implement draggable tab using Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269/how-to-implement-draggable-tab-using-java-swing)

Comment: Thanks a lot, copeg. the sample codes seems a bit complicated to me, :p